# Get Jenkins Workspace files

Tags: jenkins

I am currently working on creating a simple Jenkins Plugin. I am trying to find a way to access the files in the workspace that Jenkins has.

For instance, if I have Jenkins pull my repo, it downloads all the files to a workspace folder on the computer. How would I find this exact location?

I am trying to zip the files and be able to send them out to an API endpoint. Thank you all

Comment: Add a build step called "Execute Shell" and use `pwd` to print the current workspace.

Answer (score 1):

If [developing a plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/), refer to the [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

[Before proceeding](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Before+starting+a+new+plugin), ask if "one or more plugins which cover your needs" ? eg: [HTTP Post](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http-post/) (plus, lots of ways to "zip")

Nevertheless, [hudson.FilePath](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html) probably meets your [use case](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/class-use/FilePath.html).

As [Jesse Glick explains](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/reading-and-writing-from-master-to-slave-td5007664.html):

> Just use  `FilePath newFile = build.getWorkspace().child(fileOnDiskPath);`
> unconditionally. You would typically pass a relative pathname; see:
> https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html#child-java.lang.String-

And if you want to do the compressing : [`FilePath.TarCompression`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.TarCompression.html)

Reference a workspace in a pipeline? [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.WorkspaceAction`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/actions/WorkspaceAction.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an env var called WORKSPACE that contains the location.
e.g. for a job named banana in the folder sandbox

```
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps {
            echo "$WORKSPACE"
            sh "ls $WORKSPACE"
            sh "touch banana.txt"
            sh "ls $WORKSPACE"
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the output

```
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
[Pipeline] echo
/tmp/workspace/sandbox/banana
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls /tmp/workspace/sandbox/banana
[Pipeline] sh
+ touch banana.txt
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls /tmp/workspace/sandbox/banana
banana.txt
```

Comment: OP is "creating a simple Jenkins Plugin", not trying to just determine workspace value.